cenken and censeaken functions with multiple DLs
My question is about the cenken and censeaken functions (in R) from NADA and NADA2 packages: do these functions consider multiple detection limits in their analysis, or the user needs to re-censor the data to maximum DL before entering these two functions?
If the answer is they do consider multiple detection limits, a reliable and accessible resource will be much appreciated.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

My recollection is they do not--but you should check the manual pages to be sure.  I have had to write my own R code for multiply-censored regression responses -- but that was nearly 10 years ago.  NADA was around, but perhaps somebody else has contributed more flexible solutions in the meantime.  The resource for NADA, of course, is the NADA book.
